# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" only in production build

Tags: reactjs

I've build an app with `create-react-app` and while everything works fine in development, once I run `npm run build` and start the application with the production build files, I get:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ri (react-dom.production.min.js:156)
    at gi (react-dom.production.min.js:167)
    at Object.Oi [as useEffect] (react-dom.production.min.js:167)
    at Object.t.useEffect (react.production.min.js:22)
    at w (makeStyles.js:191)
    at S (makeStyles.js:228)
    at withStyles.js:55
    at ai (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Ni (react-dom.production.min.js:176)
    at Vu (react-dom.production.min.js:271)
```

I've went through the code and I've added optional chaining everywhere I try to access `length` but the error is still there. I'm not sure why would this error only show in build and not in development.
I can't post specific code because I'm not sure where or why is this error showing up, so any pointers are welcome.

EDIT:
If I go to the minified .js file, this is where it says the error happens.

```
function Bh(a, b) {
    if (null === b)
        return !1;
    for (var c = 0; c < b.length && c < a.length; c++)
        if (!He(a[c], b[c]))
            return !1;
    return !0
}
```

EDIT 2:
I've commented every line of code where I access `length` and I've deleted the `build` folder and run `npm run build` again but the error is still there.

**ANSWER**: I've somehow solved the error but I'm not sure how. I think that the reason was because of `makeStyles` and `withStyles` in the functional components as there is no need to use `withStyles` there.

Comment: If you look at `react-dom.production.min.js:156`, what do you see?

Comment: @Dominik I've added it to the post.

Comment: @DjangoDev1 Thanks your answer helped me so much. Please post your answer under the answer's section for others benefit. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we are trying to access a `key` value which is of type array and check the length it.
Ex:

```
const someData = [
  {
    tags: []
  },{
    id: '1',
    tags: []
  }
]

someData.map((x) => {
  const length = x.tags.length; // this works fine
})
```

Where as

```
const someData = [
  {
    tags: []
  },{
    id: '1',
  }
]

someData.map((x) => {
  const length = x.tags.length; // [ERR]: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 

})
```

The reason it is not working in production build might be because, that particular `data` is missing some `key` values. Try checking the DB **record** of that account.

Comment: I've commented every line of code where I access `length` and I've deleted the `build` folder and run `npm run build` again but the error is still there.